# how to get the last record number after inserting record to database in access

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

i have database in access with auto increase field (`ID`).

i insert record like this (in C#)

```
SQL = "insert into TermNumTbl (DeviceID,IP) values ('" + DeviceID + "','" + DeviceIP + "') ";
OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, Conn);
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Cmd.Dispose();
Conn.Close();
```

how to get the last inserting number ?

i dont want to run new query i know that in sql there is something like `SELECT @@IDENTITY`

but i dont know how to use it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

More about this : [Getting the identity of the most recently added record](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record)

The Jet 4.0 provider supports `@@Identity`

```
string query = "Insert Into Categories (CategoryName) Values (?)";
string query2 = "Select @@Identity";
int ID;
string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdb";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
{
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))

  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Category.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = query2;
    ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  }
}
```

Comment: you should add link to original article, because everything is copy/pasted from it.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you could even write an extension method for `OleDbConnection`...

```
public static int GetLatestAutonumber(
    this OleDbConnection connection)
{
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY;", connection))
    {
        return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Niced solution! worked for me when others wouldn't. I escaped the extension method in my use though as seen in my modified post.

Answer (score 0):

I like more indicate the type of command 
is very similar to the good solution provided by Pranay Rana

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = sql_Insert;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        cmd.CommandText = sql_obtainID;
                        resultado = (int)comando.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 query = "Insert Into jobs (jobname,daterecieved,custid) Values ('" & ProjectNAme & "','" & FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.ShortDate) & "'," & Me.CustomerID.EditValue & ");"'Select Scope_Identity()"
        ' Using cn As New SqlConnection(connect)

          Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, cnPTA)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryName", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer)
                If cnPTA.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cnPTA.Open()
                ID = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
          End Using
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Lee.J.Baxter 's method (Which was great as the others id not work for me!) I escaped the Extension Method and just added it inline within the form itself:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='{0}'", DBPath));
OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
con.Open();
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO Tasks (TaskName, Task, CreatedBy, CreatedByEmail, CreatedDate, EmailTo, EmailCC) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')", subject, ConvertHtmlToRtf(htmlBody), fromName, fromEmail, sentOn, emailTo, emailCC);
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY;", con))
{
    ReturnIDCast =(int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

**NOTE:** In most cases you should use Parameters instead of the string.Format() method I used here. I just did so this time as it was quicker and my insertion values are not coming from a user's input so it should be safe.

Answer (score -2):

Simple,

What we do in excel for copy text in above cell?

Yes, just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> combination,
and yes, it's work in MS ACCESS also.

You can use above key stroke combination for copy above records field text, just make sure if you have duplicate verification applied or edit field data before move next field.

If you aspects some more validation or any extraordinary then keep searching stack overflow.

Comment: OP was, likely, looking for a programming solution. A helpful answer is already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230309/6670491).