# Multi insert with scope_identity how to?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a issue with SSIS OLE DB Command.

What I'm trying to do, is insert into "person" table and grab the newly created `PersonID` (table identity) from the insert, as I need this to create a relation into a PersonContactInfo table, this should be pretty simple.

I'm unable to write a stored procedure and there are around 10k rows so it should be okay with a OLE DB Command.

I have tried to write this code and it should match the:

```
DECLARE @PersonID int
---
--- create new person
---
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Personer_LF_TEST] (Fornavne, Efternavne, Oprindelse, OprettetDato, OprettetAf,OprindelseID)
VALUES (?, ?, 'Klimaquiz', ?, 499,7)

SET @PersonID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

---
--- update phonenumber
---
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Kontaktinfo_LF_TEST](PersonID, KontaktInfoTypeID, Notat, Tekst, Oprettet)
VALUES (@PersonID, 5, ?,?, Getdate() )

---
--- update Email
---
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Kontaktinfo_LF_TEST](PersonID, KontaktInfoTypeID, Notat, Tekst, Oprettet)
VALUES (@PersonID, 2,?, ?, Getdate() )

---
--- create persontypecode
---
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PersonArtskoder_LF_TEST](PersonID, ArtskoderID, Notat, Aktiv, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, StartDato, SlutDato)
VALUES (@PersonID,?, ?, 1, 209, getdate(), 209, getdate(), getdate(), NULL )
```

I have also tried just to run the first part with success like this:

```
-- Create new Person
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Personer_LF_TEST](Fornavne, Efternavne, Oprindelse, OprettetDato, OprettetAf, OprindelseID)
VALUES (?, ?,'Klimaquiz',?,499,7)
```

that inserts the 10k rows

If try and do this, it fails

```
-- Create new person
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Personer_LF_TEST](Fornavne, Efternavne, Oprindelse, OprettetDato, OprettetAf, OprindelseID)
VALUES(?, ?, 'Klimaquiz', ?, 499, 7)
-- Insert Phone number
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Kontaktinfo_LF_TEST](PersonID, KontaktInfoTypeID, Tekst, Oprettet)
VALUES (1, 5, ?, Getdate())
```

The error is:

> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Command [178]]: SSIS Error Code
>   dts_E_OLEDBERROR. an OLE DB error has occurred.
>
> Error Code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "
>   Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Insert value list does not match column list"

But the input should match column list.

This is "kinda" the code that I would like the OLD DB Command to execute

```
DECLARE @PersonID int
---
--- create new person
---
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Personer_LF_TEST](Fornavne, Efternavne, Oprindelse, OprettetDato, OprettetAf,OprindelseID)
VALUES  ('Simster', 'Mann', 'Klimaquiz', '03-25-2019', 499,7)
SET @PersonID = (SELECT scope_identity())
---
--- update phonenumber
---
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Kontaktinfo_LF_TEST](PersonID, KontaktInfoTypeID, Notat, Tekst, Oprettet)
VALUES  (@PersonID, 5, 'WEB','22004400', Getdate() )
---
--- update Email
---
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Kontaktinfo_LF_TEST](PersonID, KontaktInfoTypeID, Notat, Tekst, Oprettet)
VALUES  (@PersonID, 2,'WEB', 'Simster@codewithme.dk', Getdate() )
---
--- create persontypecode
---
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[PersonArtskoder_LF_TEST](PersonID, ArtskoderID, Notat, Aktiv, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, StartDato, SlutDato)
VALUES  (@PersonID,'30395', 'WEB', 1, 209, getdate(), 209, getdate(), getdate(), NULL )
```

Comment: If I execute this query with dummy data in SSMS i have no problem executing It

Answer (score 1):

If I execute this query with dummy data in SSMS i have no problem executing It,

```
DECLARE @PersonID int
---
--- create new person
---
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Personer_LF_TEST](Fornavne, Efternavne, Oprindelse, OprettetDato, OprettetAf,OprindelseID)
VALUES  ('TEST', 'Simmy', 'Klimaquiz', GETDATE(), 499,7)
SET @PersonID = (SELECT scope_identity())
---
--- update phonenumber
---
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Kontaktinfo_LF_TEST](PersonID, KontaktInfoTypeID, Notat, Tekst, Oprettet)
VALUES  (@PersonID, 5, 'WEB',33445566, Getdate() )
---
--- update Email
---
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Kontaktinfo_LF_TEST](PersonID, KontaktInfoTypeID, Notat, Tekst, Oprettet)
VALUES  (@PersonID, 2,'WEB', 'simster@codewithme.dk', Getdate() )
---
--- create persontypecode
---
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[PersonArtskoder_LF_TEST](PersonID, ArtskoderID, Notat, Aktiv, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, StartDato, SlutDato)
VALUES  (@PersonID,'30895', 'WEB', 1, 209, getdate(), 209, getdate(), getdate(), NULL )
```

I get 4 rows inserted with success  but i can't get It to work in the OLE DB Command object. My thought was to add a column to the flow and then add a execute sql command after data flow, the execute SQL command would then based on the input in the column either insert, update or drop/do nothing. But this seems like a tedious way around it.

Comment: Is this an addendum to the question?

Comment: You have posted this as an answer.   Does that mean your problem is solved?

Comment: You can modify your original post with new information (and it is good to mark such as an edit, or an update). I recommend you do so, and then delete this Answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach might be to break this into pieces.

Adding an edit to handle this is SSIS using this link http://radacad.com/output-parameter-of-stored-procedure-in-ole-db-command-ssis:

1. Read your data into data flow.

1.1 (EDIT) Add a derived column and set ID as null(dt_int)

2. Use an OLE DB command to insert a new row and return scope identity into a column.

2.1 (EDIT) Map your column to output parameter of stored procedure that returns scope_identity()

3. Use a multicast and set 3 new paths to derived columns
4. Use derived columns to enter the hardcoded values
5. Use OLEDB Destination to insert all the records at once.

This allows you to bulk insert the 3 subsequent queries.

***Late Edit:***

Like I said, I am quick to C# script component and this is an example of how to do that...

[how to get the last record number after inserting record to database in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230200/how-to-get-the-last-record-number-after-inserting-record-to-database-in-access)

Comment: Thanks KeithL, do you have a link on how to get the OLE DB to return the ID into a column ?I have looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914818/insert-a-single-row-and-return-its-primary-key ......but here they put it in a SSIS variable but that won't work for me ... :-S

Comment: I have to admit. I would be quick to jump to c# but this looks like a great example of how to use SSIS for this. http://radacad.com/output-parameter-of-stored-procedure-in-ole-db-command-ssis

Comment: but if it is not possible to create a stored procedure ? then your solution would'nt work ? :-(

Comment: Added a link to how to do step 2 in C# Script component